# I want to write a fluent property like Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
this.Property(f => f.Id)
  .IsRequired()
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
   this.Property(f => f.PersianName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30)
            .HasColumnType( "nVarChar" );
```

I want to add something like this

```
this.Property(f => f.PersianName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30)
            .HasColumnType( "nVarChar" )
            .MyMethod("MyArg"); // How add this to entity Configuration
```

and I need corresponding `[MyMethod("MyArg")]`  attribute too.How get Info of this in my code this set for what property and what is that values ?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the conventions in ef6-class: ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration

You could write an extension method:

```
public virtual ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration MyMethod(this ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration , string yourParam) 
{ 
    ...
}
```